# Clarify that the Community user pokes questions with no upvoted answers.

Tags: feature-request, community-user

On the [Community User's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) page, it says that one of it's tasks is to

> Randomly poke old **unanswered** questions every hour so they get some attention

But some of the questions I have seen have answers on them. I think that in this case, it means that if there are answers, then they have no upvotes, but I think this needs to be better clarified.

The wording could read as such

> Randomly poke old questions with no upvoted answers every hour so they get some attention

Comment: I agree with you in-principle; but... "Unanswered questions" has a different meaning in Stack Exchange Network. The [Unanswered Tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) describes them as *questions with no upvoted answers*.

Comment: "I think that in this case, it means that if there are answers, then they have no upvotes"

Comment: @CodyGuldner That clarification is not needed because "unanswered questions" means exactly that.

Comment: But for users that don't know what that means, it can be quite confusing. Because there is also a tab on SO that actually gives questions with no answers

Comment: No, that tab doesn't. It's just the first ones that have no answers at all. On latter pages within that tab, the questions do have answers.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50) tab gives unanswered questions.

Comment: @CodyGuldner Go to the last page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css?page=465&sort=unanswered&pagesize=50

Comment: The point is that it can be quite confusing

Comment: @CodyGuldner [See the tooltip](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2JooR.png)

Comment: @CodyGuldner If that is really your problem, then your request should be to change or clarify the definition of "unanswered question". Just changing it for the Community user would be somewhat pointless.

Comment: @Bart We actually have two definitions of "unanswered". On the top-level Unanswered tab (that leads to stackoverflow.com/unanswered) it means "no answers at all". On the [questions list sorted by unanswered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered), it means "no upvoted answers". Introducing some consistency of definition here couldn't hurt. That said, I don't think the Community user's profile is a source of mass confusion and the Cody's proposed wording is more verbose for little benefit.

Comment: @AnnaLear The questions visible at stackoverflow.com/unanswered seem to disagree with your first point?

Comment: @Bart Foiled by second-level tabs. Good lord, our UI for this is terrible. Try http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=noanswers.

Comment: @AnnaLear Yep, that does it. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Yeah we kinda need to fix the definition of unanswered. Should I post a new question for that?

Comment: @CodyGuldner If you like. I believe some sort of a front page redesign is on our list of things to eventually get to, and hopefully that would also clarify the definitions. But it never hurts to have a specific request. :)

Comment: Do we really need to fight the English language?  The default assumption of most users as to what "unanswered" means is almost certainly going to be "no answers".  They might make a *second* guess that it means "no *accepted* answers"...but "no upvoted answers" is a *distant* third place!

Comment: @A.M. Agreed. This should be clarified